# Build Qt with the specific openssl version

Tags: qt, openssl, debian

I need to built Qt with the openssl lib version 1.0.2k. But in the OS I use (Debian 7 x64) there is the 1.0.1 version is installed by default. I've already built the needed version from source code, so I have it. But Qt still is being built with the 1.0.1 version. 
I've already tried to substitute openssl in the "/usr/bin/" directory and set the directory with the new libs ("usr/local/ssl/lib/", cuz "usr/local/ssl" is the directory with openssl-1.0.2k) to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but it isn't work, Qt is still being built with openssl-1.0.1.

Maybe somedoby know how to define the new version of openssl for the building of Qt?

When I'm building Qt, I use the following configuration and version 5.6.3 of Qt:

```
./configure -prefix $PWD/qtbase -release -opensource -confirm-license -static -accessibility -openssl-linked
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to modify the debian source package and rebuild the Debian package instead of building from source.

But this requires some knowledge about how Debian packages are built.

Otherwise chances are high that Qt somehow relieas on pkgconfig to find the right openssl library. So try changing libcrypto.pc and libssl.pc. Or Override your PKG_CONFIG_PATH